# Need help finding why CSS not working in IE

Tags: css

i have some issues with [my site](http://jiewmeng.tumblr.com) CSS i developed the site without IE and now when i try to fix IE bugs the problems seem so overwhelming, what and how will u use to debug? it seems like a bug in tumblr cause invalid code to be generated? hmm ... its ok in firefox tho lol

```
<a _blank="" target=" target=" href="http://fadeyev.net/2010/06/19/lessjs-will-obsolete-css/">Less.js Will Obsolete CSS</a>
```

Comment: <!--[if IE]<script>window.location="http://www.mozilla.com/firefox/"</script>![endif]-->

Comment: a better solution i found will be to use [Google Chrome Frame](http://code.google.com/chrome/chromeframe/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't blame this on css or IE. Its problems with your a tag..

```
<a _blank="" target=" target=" href="http://fadeyev.net/2010/06/19/lessjs-will-obsolete-css/">Less.js Will Obsolete CSS</a>
```

Should be

```
<a target="_blank" href="http://fadeyev.net/2010/06/19/lessjs-will-obsolete-css/">Less.js Will Obsolete CSS</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Making sites IE-compatible is a lifelong endeavour. IE's own [developer toolbar](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=e59c3964-672d-4511-bb3e-2d5e1db91038&displaylang=en) helps a lot. [QuirksMode](http://quirksmode.org/) has a formidable library of browser compatibility information. I see you're already using jQuery and a CSS template, but it bears repeating that piggybacking on frameworks that have already been developed with compatibility in mind helps a lot. If you're not comfortable running virtual machines, [Browser Shots](http://browsershots.org/) is a pretty good tool to make sure your site works a variety of OS/browser combinations. Finally, I would consider IE6 to have a [low enough market share](http://www.w3schools.com/browsers/browsers_stats.asp) to justify not concerning yourself with that level of compatibility.

Comment: About that market share: w3schools.com is mostly visited by people interested in web design and it is more likely that they use a more modern browser than IE 6. In real life, I come across IE 6 many times, like in several companies, university computers, public libraries, etc. Also read [Why the NHS can't get its browser act together](http://www.guardian.co.uk/technology/2010/jan/22/internet-explorer-nhs-vulnerability)…